# Can't import a shapefile with different SRID in a geometry column

Tags: postgis, import, srid

PostgreSQL 13, PostGIS 3, QGIS 3.22

In a table, I had a geometry column geom with a SRID 2154.
Now I have to store geometries with different SRIDs in geom. So I did :

```
alter table activite.prescription
alter column geom type geometry(MULTIPOLYGON, 0),
```

to be able to store different SRIDs, replacing 2154 with 0.

```
SELECT Find_SRID('activite', 'prescription', 'geom')
```

returns 0 as expected.

Now I try to upload a shapefile with a SRID 5490 using QGIS and the plugin `export to PostgreSQL`. (The shapefile has the correct .prj file)

If the shp is imported correctly, even the geometry, its SRID is "converted" in 2154. It is not a reprojection but just a ununderstandable change. No trigger is activated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(geom) FROM activite.prescription
```

returns just **one** SRID 2154!

When I load the layer in QGIS choosing 5490 to display the feature, the layer is indeed empty.

When I run a query like `select st_setsrid(geom)...` applied to the feature imported, it returns 2154 so to speak the SRID initially existing.

Why can't I keep the different SRIDs?

**EDIT** : Even if I use select  `select st_setsrid(geom, 5490)...` on the imported feature to change its SRID, it doesn't change anything : the SRID stays 2154. Weird or there is an explanation I ignore (I'd prefer!)? And I have no error message.

Comment: Most GIS tools won't allow a source with multiple SRIDs, so it seems as if you are trying to force your way past protection against failure.

Comment: Mixing SRIDs in a single column is a bad idea... it will make spatial operation difficult or unreliable - if even possible. You can instead use 2 columns, one for each SRID.

Comment: I have to manage 7 SRIDS. What is weird to me is that if we can mix several SRIDs in a single column, SRIDs are lost after the imports. So what is the point ?

Answer (score 1):

`st_setsrid` will return a **new** geometry with the updated projection. It is not an in-place update

```
UPDATE myTable
SET geom = st_setSRID(geom,4326);
```

Comment: that is not what I understand from the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html). It is used for a feature.

Comment: I agree the doc could be clearer. It subtly indicates that the function returns a `geometry`, and it does not mention in-place update so it shouldn't be assumed.